# What is wrong with setting primary key with my tables? "Equal or Remove Advice"

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, primary-key

I have created this table in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE ACESSO -- cadastro de usuários para acesso ao sistema
(
    ACESSO_ID           CHAR(20) UNIQUE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,   
    LICENCIADO          CHAR(20), -- identifica a qual empresa este usuário faz parte, conectando o acesso de acordo com o registro do sistema  
    CADASTRO            CHAR(20) NOT NULL, -- cadastro da tabela de cpf
    SITUACAO            ENUM('NORMAL','BLOQUEADO','SUSPENSO'), 
    SENHA               CHAR(32) NOT NULL,                          
    DISPOSITIVO         VARCHAR(11), -- número do chip celular 3g usado no coletor de dados
    PERFIL              ENUM('LICENCIADO','ADMINISTRADOR','OPERADOR','ENTREVISTADOR','SISTEMA'), 
    ACESSOS             INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0, -- número de acessos ao sistema
    ULTIMO_ACESSO       DATETIME, -- data e hora do último acesso ao sistema
    COMENTARIOS         VARCHAR(255), -- qualquer texto de interesse do administrador do sistema sobre este usuário
    UNIQUE INDEX (CADASTRO, LICENCIADO)  -- estes dois indices permitem que hava mais de um cadastro com o mesmo cpf e email
)
ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8  COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
```

When I compile it in PHPMyAdmin, I it works but I get this advice:

```
"The indexing PRIMARY and ACESSO_ID appear to be equal or one of them may have been removed."
```

As shown in this picture:

[image]

**Will I have future problems with my tables?** All of them shows that message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primary key already Unique.

Just remove Unique.

Comment: Will I have problems if I leave it as it is?

Comment: No, but you will get that warning and fill uncomfortable :)